# how java implements finally block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, finally

I have searched a lot to find the implementation of **finally block** by java implementers.

I want to know how java evaluates finally block.

Does anybody know how finally block is defined in java language?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Have you looked at the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)?  `finally` is not a library class/method, it's part of the language, and its behavior is specified in the JLS.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13 ?

Comment: @JimGarrison what clear making you unclear about finally, actually question is not unclear but my knowledge is unclear, that y i have posted this question here, and i have edited my question so please remove your downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is going to be JVM dependent, but will follow the [JVM Specifications #3.13](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13).

`finally` behaves like a "catch all" in the exceptions table, with the proper redirections in the bytecode.

Comment: okay ,but how java knows that, finally block must be executed even runtime exception occurs.

Comment: It knows because that's the way the compiler translated the source into bytecode. It's required to do that by the JLS. You are asking the same thing as "why does Java execute statements in order?" or "why does a for loop repeat?"  It's how the language is defined.  You don't need to worry about how this happens unless you're writing the compiler.  You just need to know that the `finally` block is executed no matter what happens inside the corresponding `try` block (except maybe in the event of power loss or physical destruction of the machine).